# Настройка urlrewrite для Битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Подскажите пожалуйста как настроить urlrewrite в битрикс для статистических страниц?

Сейчас делаю страницы в urlrewrite так

```
4 => 
array (
'CONDITION' => '#^/(?<subdomain>(\\w+))/services/#',
'RULE' => '',
'ID' => '',
'PATH' => '/services/index.php',
'SORT' => 100,
),
```

И так нужно делать с каждой страницей. На внутри services есть еще 15 страниц. Приходится делать массив под каждую страницу в urlrewrite как сделать, чтобы работали все страницы в services в urlrewrite без создания массива под каждую страницу?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить ещё правило для подстраниц:

```
5 => 
array (
'CONDITION' => '#^/(?<subdomain>(\\w+))/services/([a-zA-Z_-]+)/#',
'RULE' => 'page=$3',
'ID' => '',
'PATH' => '/services/index.php',
'SORT' => 100,
),
```

Тогда в index.php будет передаваться параметром page содержимое третьих скобок.